# Could not resolve all files for configuration for gradle build

Tags: gradle

Gradle build configuration failed even when I update to the latest version can someone suggest me what will be the resolution I have updated a couple of libraries to the latest libraries till it compliance about same issue

```
* What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':compileKotlin'.
    > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
       > Could not find any matches for io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging:+ as no versions of io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging are available.
```

Even after updating the owaspDependencyCheckVersion to '6.0.1'  and implementation("io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging:1.11.5") to still am getting compileClassPath error

```
    buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlinVersion = '1.3.50'
        springBootVersion = '2.1.7.RELEASE'
        etcdClientVersion = '2.16.0'
        owaspDependencyCheckVersion = '5.2.1'
        myBatisVersion = '2.1.0'
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${kotlinVersion}")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:${kotlinVersion}")
        classpath("org.tmatesoft.svnkit:svnkit:+")
        classpath "org.owasp:dependency-check-gradle:${owaspDependencyCheckVersion}"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-starter:${myBatisVersion}")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache")
    implementation("com.github.ben-manes.caffeine:caffeine:+")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:${kotlinVersion}")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:${kotlinVersion}")
    implementation "com.vividsolutions:jts-io:+"
    implementation("de.micromata.jak:JavaAPIforKml:+")
    implementation("org.jsoup:jsoup:+")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:+")
    implementation("org.mousio:etcd4j:+")
    implementation("net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:+")
    implementation("io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging:+")
    implementation('org.postgresql:postgresql')
    testImplementation('com.h2database:h2')
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testImplementation("com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path-assert")
    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
}
```

Comment: What repositories are configured in your `repositories` block? Are you sure the `io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging:+` dependency is available via one of these repositories?

Comment: is this the complete build.gradle file ?

Comment: @DineshDontha yes that's complete build file